# Reading in a file to create multiple "minesweeper"ish arrays

Tags: c

What I got so far, is a .in file that will create 100 arrays, followed by how many "mines" are on the board, and then 2 numbers for each "mine" representing where they will be placed on the array. This is for my beginner C class, and honestly we've not been taught properly for something this advanced (i say advanced using the term lightly). I know how to read in files, and I know how to create an array, but im unsure how I would read in that many lines, switching from mines to placement over and over again. I also find myself confused as to how to change an array number from 0 to another number based on where a mine is placed.

An example input file:

```
1
4
1 3
7 5
7 3
3 3
```

Where the `1` in the first line means we have one board. The `4` on the next line means it will have 4 bombs. The following 4 lines describe the position of the bomb in the array as `row column`.

Is there anything that anyone can offer me to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Besides what you have tried, can you describe what you have been taught? Have you been taught `for` or `while` loops? What input functions have you been taught? And also, try to be a little more specific about what you are trying to do; can you show an example of a file that you are trying to read in, or an excerpt from it?

Comment: oh yeah, I suppose some basic information would help. I have been taught for/ while/ and do-while loops, if statements. Dunno what you mean by input functions, so im guessing none.

Comment: I basically  need an array of 8x8 to print out 9's wherever a mine is to be placed, and the numbers around it to change, adding 1 for each mine next to it. I cant figure out how to print the sample input and output on the board with linebreaks. sorry for seeming like an idiot, first time on these boards

Comment: @ChrisMiranda could you provide an example of the form of the input file? Without knowing this one can't do much more than guess the input from your textual description, which makes it hard to offer any useful help. I understand what you want to do once you've read in the file, but it's not clear what the file looks like at the moment.

Comment: the file is read in in multiple steps, starting with the first line as the number of boards to be made. Second is the number of bombs on any given board, then for each bomb there is a set of two numbers on each line after that.

Comment: so if i were to have 1 as my first line, it would have one board, then if there were a 4 on the next line, it would have 4 bombs, and then the next 4 lines would have 2 numbers separated by a space and those numbers would represent the row and column of my array and have a 9 placed there to represent the mine

Answer (score 0):

Below is a partial solution, it leaves a few parts as an exercise for the OP.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BOARD_SIZE 8

int main(void) {

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("mines.in","r");
    if ( fp == NULL ) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Could not open file\n");
            return 1;
    }

    int nBoards = 0;
    int nMines  = 0;
    int col;
    int row;

    int currentBoard = 0;

    /* We know the first row is going to be the number of boards */
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&nBoards);

    printf("We have %d boards\n",nBoards);

    while ( fscanf(fp,"%d",&nMines) > 0 ) {
            int i,j;
            /* initialize board as all zeros */
            int board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE] = { {0} };

            currentBoard++;
            printf("Board %d:\n",currentBoard);

            /* Read in and set the mines */
            for (i=0; i<nMines; i++) {
                    fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&col,&row);
                    board[col-1][row-1] = 9;
            }

            /* Add mine proximity */
            for (i=0; i<BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
                    for (j=0; j<BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
                            if ( board[i][j] == 9 ) { /* we have a mine */
                                    /* Square to the left */
                                    if (j > 0 && board[i][j-1] != 9) {
                                            board[i][j-1]++;
                                    }
                                    /* Square to the right */
                                    /* Left as exercise for the OP*/

                                    /* Square above */
                                    /* Left as exercise for the OP*/

                                    /* Square below */
                                    /* Left as exercise for the OP*/
                    }
            }

            /* Print out the board */
            for (i=0; i<BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
                    for (j=0; j<BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
                            printf("%d ",board[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);

    if (currentBoard != nBoards) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Expected %d boards, read in %d  boards\n",nBoards,currentBoard);
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code reads in the first line to record the number of boards, then it loops over the blocks of data containing the number of mines and the mine locations. The `while` loop will perform an `fscanf` on the lines containing the number of mines, and in the body of the while loop the different mine locations will be read in to the number defined for the board.

Once we have all the mine locations we can calculate the numbers in other squares on the board, only one of which I've shown in the code (others are similar).

Note that the above code does almost no error handling and almost no validation on the input file - if the input file is wrong you could get errors i.e. 'out of range' accesses to arrays. I've left out such checks to make the underlying logic of the program clearer.

Note also that I've assumed that the input indexs are '1'-indexed (i.e. in the range [1,8] rather than '0'-indexed as C expects (i.e. in the range [0,7]), hence the substitution of 1 in the line `board[col-1][row-1] = 9;`.